# ValueError invalid literal for int() with base 10, for Twitter Bot coded in python with tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

I am currently coding a Twitter bot. I am running into this problem while trying to automate an answer, like and retweet.

The error message is :

- line 45, in  reply()
- line 35, in reply tweets= api.mentions_timeline(read_last_seen(FILE_NAME), tweet_mode='extended')
- line 24, in read_last_seen file_seen_id = int(file_read.read().strip())
- ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '`

I tried tweeking around those lines but nothing worked and wondered where was the ValueError issue.

Here is my code at the moment:

```py
FILE_NAME = 'last_seen.txt'

def read_last_seen(FILE_NAME):
    file_read = open(FILE_NAME, 'r')
    file_seen_id = int(file_read.read().strip())
    file_read.close()
    return file_seen_id

def store_last_seen(FILE_NAME, last_seen_id):
    file_write = open(FILE_NAME, 'w')
    file_write.write(str(last_seen_id))
    file_write.close()
    return

def reply():
    tweets= api.mentions_timeline(read_last_seen(FILE_NAME), tweet_mode='extended')
    for tweet in reversed(tweets):
        if '#WeatherBot_Gif' in tweet.full_text.lower():
            print(str(tweet.id) + ' -' + tweet.full_text)
            api.update_status("@" + tweet.user.screen_name + "Auto reply, like, and retweet works :)", tweet.id)
            api.create_favorite(tweet.id)
            api.retweet(tweet.id)
            store_last_seen(FILE_NAME, tweet.id)

while True:
    reply()
    time.sleep(15)
```

Also, I followed the tutorial from Certified Recaps "How to create the ultimate Twitter Bot with Python", that you can find here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewq-91-e2fw

I am a total beginner as this is my first project in Pyhton.
Would appreciate any hellp !

Have a nice day :)

Comment: are you sure `file_read.read().strip()` is returning a number and not alphabets?

Comment: @monte how can I check so ? normally it should return an id, the ID of the last tweet seen